# Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '_method' in 'field list'

Tags: laravel-5.8

I want to update a faq form. but I get this error.

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '_method' in 'field list' (SQL: update `faqs` set `_method` = PUT, `_token` = Kz2Wkgd44UA3nOVzmE8PhCGH66ywP296UqUQR8m6, `title` = q, `body` = q, `faqs`.`updated_at` = 2019-09-15 18:55:06 where `faqs`.`user_id` = 1 and `faqs`.`user_id` is not null)

FaqController.php

```
public function update(FaqRequest $request, Faq $faq)
{
    auth()->user()->faq()->update($request->all());
    return redirect()->route('faq.index');
}
```

edit.blade.php

```
<form action="{{ route('faq.update', $faq->id ) }}" method="post">
    @method('PUT')
    @csrf
    @include('errors.validate')
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="title">title</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control col-md-3" id="title" name="title" value="{{ old('title') ? : $faq->title }}">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="body">body</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" rows="10" id="body" name="body">{{ old('body')  ? : $faq->body }}</textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">save</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

User.php

```
public function faq()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Faq::class);
}
```

Faq.php

```
class Faq extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'faqs';

    protected $guarded = [];

    protected $fillable = ['title', 'body'];
}
```

Comment: use except to avoid key _method in request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$request->except(...)`, e.g. by modifying the function to

```
public function update(FaqRequest $request, Faq $faq)
{
    auth()->user()->faq()->update($request->except('_method', '_token'));

    return redirect()->route('faq.index');
}
```

Comment: i'm using the method ```public function update(StoreAccountsRequest $request, $id)
    {
        $user = User::findOrFail($id);
        
        $user->Accounts()->update($request->except('_method', '_token'))->where('accounts.user_id', '$user');
        return redirect()->route('accounts.index')->with(['message' => 'Accounts updated successfully']);
    }``` but i'm getting the error **Call to a member function where() on integer**

Comment: where('accounts.user_id', $user->id);

Comment: Avoid quotes for variable